# How to convert iqueryable<string> to string in linq?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i have the following code snippet.
in which i just want to return PartyName as a string.
but i get the error:"Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Linq.Iqueryable to string"
if i want to return only string then what to do?
please help me.

`return objDatabase.FAPARs
                   .Where(f => (f.PARTY_CODE == "P003"))
                   .Select(f => f.PARTY_NAME);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `IQueryable<string>` represents a query which could return *any number of strings*. You want *one* string - so you need to decide what to do in various situations:

- What do you want to happen if the query has no results?
- What do you want to happen if the query has one result? (I assume this is simple :)
- What do you want to happen if the query has more than one result?

The set of methods which allow you to determine all of this are:

- `Single` - fail if there isn't *exactly* one result
- `SingleOrDefault` - fail if there's more than one result, return null if there are no results
- `First` - fail if there are no results, return the first of many
- `FirstOrDefault` - return null if there are no results, or the first of many
- `Last` - fail if there are no results, return the last of many
- `LastOrDefault` - return null if there are no results, or the last of many

In each case, "fail" means "throw an exception". (IIRC it's always `InvalidOperationException`, at least in LINQ to Objects, but I could be wrong.)

So if you're querying by an ID which *must* exist (i.e. it's a bug if it doesn't) then `Single` is probably appropriate. If you're querying by an ID which *may not* exist, then use `SingleOrDefault` and check whether the return value is null. If you're *not* querying by an ID, you *probably* want to use `FirstOrDefault` or just iterate over the results.

(Note that the default value being `null` is due to this being a query returning strings, and string being a reference type. In general it's the default value of the element type - so if you had an `IQueryable<int>`, the default returned would be 0.)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
return objDatabase.FAPARs .Where(f => (f.PARTY_CODE == "P003")) .Select(f => f.PARTY_NAME).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return objDatabase.FAPARs.FirstOrDefault(f => f.PARTY_CODE.Equals("P003")).PARTY_NAME
```

Comment: You can set it as an answer :)

Comment: no dear i gate the following error: "cannot convert string to boolean" but i get the solution is as below:                  return objDatabase.FAPARs
.Where(f => (f.PARTY_CODE == "P003"))
                    .Select(f => f.PARTY_NAME).SingleOrDefault();

Comment: `return objDatabase.FAPARs .Where(f => (f.PARTY_CODE == "P003")) .Select(f => f.PARTY_NAME).SingleOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return objDatabase.FAPARs.Where(f => (f.PARTY_CODE == "P003")).Single(f => f.PARTY_NAME);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 return objDatabase.FAPARs.OfType<FAPAR>()
                .Where(f => (f.PARTY_CODE == PartyCode && f.COMP_NO == ComCode))
                .Select(f => f.PARTY_NAME).SingleOrDefault();
```